# Why doesn't vim accept \? in substitute()?

Tags: vim

```
:echo substitute("15", "15\?", "replaced", "")
15
```

`:help substitute()` reports that we are `cpoptions` is empty and we're using `magic` and some other small differences (that don't seem to point to `\?` not working).

A file with the following:

```
15
```

followed by

```
:%s/\m15\?/replaced/
```

will indeed replace the `15` with `replaced`.

Can anybody point out to me the divergence here and where the manual explains this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
:echo substitute("15", "15\\?", "replaced", "")
```

In double quotes, `\` is *interpreted*. For example, `"\n"` is the newline, `"\\"` is the backslash character `\`, etc. As the expression `"\?"` does not have a special interpretation, it just becomes a question mark `?`, and therefore you are in effect providing the regex `15?` to the function. So you need to escape `\` in order to make the string be recognized as `\?` by Vim.

Alternatively, you can use single quotes ("literal-string"), which does not interpret but takes `\` as is:

```
:echo substitute("15", '15\?', "replaced", "")
```

(To see the difference, try `echo "\?"` and `echo '\?'`.)

Some relevant help entries are `:help expr-"` and `:help expr-'`